# с чего начать разработку эмулятора процессора?

Tags: java, ассемблер, информатика, cpu

Передо мной стоит вот такая задача: 
Разработать эмулятор процессора, создать для него язык ассемблера и написать несколько программ. Нужно придумать свою архитектуру CPU и придумать ряд команд, почитайте про современные архитектуры и например наборы команд SSE и AVX.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я понял так(хотя понимание пока очень поверхностное): 
Мне не надо напрямую возиться с регистрами и все такое? Главное на логическом уровне все правильно сделать а не физическом? То есть можно взять любой ЯП, например Java, и на нем писать процессор? Он не будет иметь ничего общего с физическими процессорами, но по логике будем им соответствовать.  То есть у нас может быть программа, в которой создан массив - наша эмуляция памяти, например так:  long[] memory = new long[1024 * 1024]. Еще один массив - эмулирет регистры. Наша основная программа стартует, создаются оба массива, дальше она начинает считывать из заранее заготовленного файла по одной строке. А вот в файле мы заранее напишем нашу систему команд - Логические - and, or, not, xor. Численные - add, sub, mul, div. Программа будет их считывать и выполнять. То есть в основной функции программы, которая считывает и выполняет команды, можно будет написать switch если add -> складываем, если mul ->  умножаем  и т.д. Подскажите пожалуйста, хотя бы направление мыслей правильное?

Comment: В общих чертах, на первых порах **именно так**. Про регистр с флагами (переполнение и т.п. результаты операций) не забудьте. Потом придется добавить *моделирование времени* (к счастью, можно в тактах процессора), систему прерываний, регистры внешних устройств (или порты ввода-вывода) и т.д. Потом напишете свою ОС и будете ее отлаживать на этой модели.

Comment: Направление мыслей правильное. Я бы порекомендовал почитать [TAOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), часть 1.4.3 (и наверное к ней всю 1.3 и 1.4).

Comment: ИМХО лучше начать с эмуляции хорошо описанного реального процессора, а в процессе поймете как придумать свой. Ну и не забываем, что паять конечно не надо, но внутреннюю логику (АЛУ и УУ в простейшем случае) писать таки придется

Comment: @rdorn, отдельно моделировать АЛУ и т.п. на таком уровне излишне. А вот выделить режимы адресации в отдельные функции (которыми будут пользоваться все case большого switch по COP) желательно.

Comment: @avp отчасти вы правы, по сути отпадает необходимость низкоуровневого моделирования АЛУ, т.е. битовых сумматоров и т.п., но сама функция имитирующая получение кода операции и операндов ни куда не денется

Comment: Автор, Вы пишете: `... А вот в файле мы заранее напишем нашу систему команд ...` / IMHO в файле длжна быть программа, точнее состояние памяти и регистров, в т.ч. IC (instruction counter), т .е. адрес команды с которой и начинаете моделирование (работу программы).

Comment: @rdorn, само  собой. Собственно этим и занимаются все части switch, моделирующие арифметику. Да, конечно, я бы добавил регистр текущей операции и регистр адреса операнда (туда помещаем текущий вычисленный абсолютный адрес памяти, для команд это, естественно IC)

Comment: @avp ненене, состояния регистров в файле быть не должно. Только программа. Для начала можно считать что исполнение любой программы начинается с 0-адреса. Потом уже усложнять

Comment: @avp сдается мне скоро автор перестанет нас понимать %) и придется писать коллективный ответ =)

Comment: @rdorn, это уже детали. Но на старых машинах всегда был пульт с кнопочками, нажимая на которые можно было задать содержимое регистров (а разглядывая лампочки вычислять, что в них).

Comment: Я бы сказал, что вам все таки надо сразу считать весь файл, проверить синтаксическую верность инструкций. Загрузить команды, возможно уже в разобранном виде, в массив - это будет наш сегмент кода. И сразу расставить в нем к командам перехода номера инструкций куда им переходить. А то читая построчно из файла и тут же выполняя вы непонятно как будете осуществлять переход куда нибудь вперед.

Comment: @rdorn, ага, придется вспомнить как лет уже 30 назад я еще моделировал все эти параллельные вычислители.

Comment: @avp а кстати про старые машины, сдается мне в сети были исходники эмулятора сетунь и БК, можно посмотреть как в них все устроено, для ознакомления так сказать. "...как лет уже 30 назад..." я маленько моложе и начинал с ДВК-2 и 3 =)

Answer (score 4):

В целях обучения лучше взять простой процессор, который имеет задатки и много общего с реальными, но не настоящий - это 100%. В железе будет много оптимизации, которую вы не поймете и ограничений из-за жестокого реального мира, который не дает реализовать все так просто, как хотелось бы в теории.

Нам профессор показал, как от простых бинарных операций дойти до С++. В конце (все кто сдали) с легкостью доказывали инвариантность С++ программ и логических состояний процессора по шагам. Но, боюсь, что без толкового преподавателя вам не обойтись. Посмотрите на [этот пример](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2001/cmsc411/projects/DLX/proj.html), что бы просто понять, что такое ALU, вам нужно неплохо разбираться в дискретной математике. Работа с памятью не возможна без MUX DEMUX и знаний о них, что такое стэк и где хранится OP и т.д. Языки - это отдельная тема и очень обширная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Посмотрите** на [Computation Structures - Part 1](https://www.edx.org/course/computation-structures-part-1-digital-mitx-6-004-1x2) и [Computation Structures - Part 2](https://www.edx.org/course/computation-structures-part-2-computer-mitx-6-004-2x), я уверен - эти курсы дадут вам на порядок больше, нежели чем вы сами будете блуждать в бессистемных статьях вики и уж тем более тут. При все моем уважение к этому проекту, он абсолютно не академичен да и не стремится к этому.

З.Ы. Вот тут хороший набор команд - из моих реликвий )
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]